# Device tree interrupt number: where comes from?

Tags: kernel, gpio, device-tree, expander

Working with device tree cause the two question bothers me:
How does the interrupt number relate to the physical interrupt from the device?
How to know which interrupt number choose describing node in device tree?
For example below is a node for gpio expander:

```
expander: max7325@6d {
    compatible = "maxim,max7325";
    reg = <0x6d>;
    gpio-controller;
    #gpio-cells = <2>;
    interrupt-controller;
    #interrupt-cells = <2>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gpio4>;
    interrupts = <29 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
};
```

How author knew that magic 29 interrupt number will be appropriate for this device?

Comment: The `interrupts` property in the DT simply uses the hardware interrupt number from the SoC datasheet, or (for external devices) the interrupt line specified by board schematics.